# Android - locking mic to audio signal

Tags: android

Do  android sdk supports opening the Mic to lock in a audio signal which would cause the app to trigger a function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by *lock in an audio signal*.

Android SDK supports [recording audio](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) from the microphone.

The SDK has methods that allow you to be [notified periodically](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#setRecordPositionUpdateListener%28android.media.AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener%29) during recording.  In the notification method, you can do whatever you like, including execution of a function.